# Android onTouchListener: Switch Activity On User Touch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I am new to Android development, and would like some help figuring out how to do something. I have an activity with an EditText object that I have formatted to take up the whole view, with a certain word in the center. What I need to figure out is how to implement onTouchListener, so that when the user taps on the screen (anywhere) they are forwarded to another Activity.Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As your `EditText` takes up the whole view, you need to attach the `onTouchListener` to it.

In your activity code :

```
yourEditText.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener()
{
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event )
        {
            // start your other activity here
        }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks tbruyelle! But there is something here that confuses me. When I implement what you suggest, Eclipse prompts me to import the inherited abstract method for onTouchListener, which adds this to the bottom of my .java: public boolean onTouch (View arg0, MotionEvent arg1){ }...... What should I do with this?

Comment: yes clicks are going to work on your device in the same way as they work on emulator.

Comment: @embersofadyingfire : `MotionEvent` helps you to determinate the kind of touch done by the user (swipe, pinch, etc...). But on your side if I well understand, you don't need to take this into account, so you can simply ignore the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

in your .xml add this property to your EditText

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and in .java file, after initializing your EditText set onClickListener

```
mEditeText.setOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        .....
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Swati! After reviewing your suggestion, I realized that I could do the same thing I've been doing with my buttons. But this brings up a question about something I have not thought about until now: What is the difference between clicks and touches in Android? I've set up onClicks for all my buttons that take me to the next activity. Are these clicks going to work on a real device, when a user taps on the buttons? or should all of those be converted to onTouchListeners?